# Enable/Disable Workflow using Azure Workflow Management API

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-management-api, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to Enable/Disable a logic app on Azure using the management APIs. I always get a 403 saying the client: with object id  does not have authorization to perform 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/disable/action' ...
I do use the authentication token in my request and so far have been able to use the API to list all workflows, get trigger histories and in/out messages using the same method.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue a lot before if you are calling the http:// instead of https://  - we are looking into automatically redirecting, but for now you will need to make sure you are calling the https:// endpoint with the correct method (in this case a PUT)

EDIT: We discovered the issue was the account being used to perform the enable/disable didn't have contribute permissions.

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn948513.aspx I use "https://{endpoint}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/enable?api-version=2015-02-01-preview" and "https://{endpoint}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/disable?api-version=2015-02-01-preview" with POST method, I did try PUT but both cases return the mentioned error.

Comment: Do other calls work? May be something with auth - you mention you are using your authorization token for Azure Resource Manager requests  (AAD - basic auth won't work for these calls) - just make sure you have the correct syntax of Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx and not Basic xxxxxxxx

Comment: Yes, other calls work. Also I use auth token with Bearer xxx syntax. I've noticed that for this particular call, similar to retrieving the input/output links' JSON messages for the workflows, Azure portal uses OPTIONS method first to get some information back to include them in the headers of the subsequent GETs/POSTs. I won't be able to check that till Monday. I'll post if that solves the problem.

Comment: Ok I tested it out and was able to get it to work - it looks like I was mistaken and you CAN use Basic Auth if you want, you just have to make sure you follow the steps at the bottom of the doc.  If you are using AAD Auth (Bearer token), make sure you are doing a POST with the URL of https://management.azure.com/....... instead of {region}.logic.... - that's the URL only if doing Basic auth.  

With that set as the correct URL and with the base of management.azure.com since I'm using AAD Bearer auth, it worked for me.

Comment: OK ,first of all thanks for your continued follow up. I'm still not able to get it to work, I do AAD auth with POST and the URL mentioned, I actually call the same function to pull information from GetWrokflow, Get Triggers for the Workflow and Get histories on a Trigger, and they all work except this particular call. I also try with Fiddler and can do all the other calls but still get a 403 on enable/disable call. I'll have to move on for the time being, since I've spent so much time on it already.

Comment: Understand - if it helps I've copied the cURL (generated from Postman) of my call that worked so you can check out any of the info to see how it matches up.  All I changed was the sub ID and the bearer token.  It may help if you copy/paste your info as well (minus sensitive stuff) so I can compare

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer {token from armclient}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/80dxxxb03/resourceGroups/Default-Web-WestUS/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/AzureFriday/disable?api-version=2015-02-01-preview'

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with curl, but I've pasted the URl that I use here. It is in the same format as the one you have provided:<br />https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/45-xx-87b266ed55e/resourceGroups/default/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/FileConnector-LogicApp/disable?api-version=2015-02-01-preview <br /> generally in Fiddler this my request header:<br /> Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <Token-GUID>
Host: management.azure.com
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Thanks that's just what I needed - yes looks like you have everything set up correctly.  I'll notify the engineers here on this issue and we can investigate.  If you could email me your subscription ID to jehollan[at]microsoft.com I can provide it so they can try to debug from our end.  Sorry for the issues you've hit, and feel free to reach out with any other questions in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm going to take you up on "ask me anything in the meanwhile" offer. Is there a way to query the "Portal Settings" on the new Azure Portal. Things like language and Region and etc. Thanks very much.

Comment: Good question - I've looked into it but not seeing anything.  I sent an email to a few people who may know better but nothing yet.  Any specifics on why this exposed as an API would be valuable?

Comment: Thank you, at this point we were just exploring ways with which we could integrate our services as close as possible to the azure experience, one of which could have been offering the same language setting on a user's azure portal.